# テストコードとプロダクトコードをリンキングしたい

Tags: java, テスト, maven, junit

テストコードとプロダクトコードをリンキングする方法をご存知の方はおられませんでしょうか？
現在，Java でソフトウェアを開発しているのですが，ソフトウェアがやや複雑になってきました．
テストをしっかりしたいので，どのテストコードがどのプロダクトコードをテストしているのかを把握しておきたいと思いまして。。。
ご存知の方がおられましたら，教えていただけると幸いです．
ちなみにですが，maven を使ってビルドしております．
また，SonarQube を使用したことがありますので，これらのツールでリンキングができると嬉しいです．
もちろん，その他有用なツールがあれば積極的に使用したいと思います．

Comment: リンキングと仰られてる内容がテストコードとプロダクションコードの紐付けであると仮定すると、わりとよくあるのは命名規則とQuickJUnitを用いる方法ですが、本質的にはテストの状況がテストコードから把握できていないことが問題だと思うので、コードカバレッジについて調べた方がいいような気がします。

Answer (score 1):

Maven 使われているのでしたら src/main/java と src/test/java のように規約に沿ったフォルダ構成にしましょう。プロダクトコードのクラス名が FooBar とすると src/test/java 配下の FooBar と同じパッケージにテストクラスを FooBarTest という規約で作るようにしましょう。

Eclipse だと、Ctrl + 9 でテスティングペア(FooBar と FooBarTest) を行き来できますし、テストクラスが存在しない場合新規作成するか聞いてくれます。

このようにプロダクトコードとテストコードを1対1で作成するのが単体テストの一番わかりやすい構成だと思います。

結合テストなどはクラス単位でできないので、機能単位で XxxIntegrationTest のようなネーミングで作成することが多いです(別プロジェクトにすることもあります)。